# a linear algebra problem arising in geometry

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, geometry

This is a matrix problem. Assume that $A$ and $B$ are real $n\times n$ matrices. Denote $\Lambda=A+iB$, 
$$
M=\left
(\begin{array}{cc}
A &-B\\
B & A
\end{array}
\right )
$$
I would like to prove 
$$
\det M=\lvert\det\Lambda\rvert^2
$$

Thank you!

Comment: Are you sure you don't mean $|\det \Lambda|^2$?

Comment: Dave, sorry that it should be $|det\Lambda|^2$

Comment: [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Determinant#Block_matrices) references [Silvester (2000) *Determinants of Block Matrices*](http://dx.doi.org/10.2307/3620776) for $\det M$ but I don't see anything in there yet to handle $\det\Lambda$.

Comment: Are you given that $A,B$ commute? If so, it looks easy. If not, what makes you think it is true. Have you tried to find a counter-example?

Answer (score 3):

**HINT:** Use some basic determinant identities with the following equality:
$$
\begin{bmatrix}
I&0\\
-iI&I
\end{bmatrix}
\begin{bmatrix}
A+iB & -B \\ 0 & A-iB
\end{bmatrix}
\begin{bmatrix}
I & 0 \\
iI & I
\end{bmatrix}
=\begin{bmatrix}
A&-B\\
B&A
\end{bmatrix}.
$$

Comment: Neat. I like it :)